# Maximum and minimum value in an Array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I wrote a Ruby code to get max and min values from an array. The code prints the max value (8) correct but it's not printing the minimum value (2). Please let me know what went wrong in my code.

```
class MaxMinArray
  def MaxMinMethod()
    array = [4,2,8,3,5]
    maxNo = array[0]
    minNo = array[0]
    arrayLength = array.length
    for i in 1..arrayLength
      if array[i].to_i > maxNo
        maxNo = array[i]
      end
      if array[i].to_i < minNo
        minNo = array[i]
      end
    end
    puts "Maximum no. in the given array: " + maxNo.to_s
    puts "Minimum no. in the given array: " + minNo.to_s
  end
end

MaxiMinArrayObj = MaxMinArray.new
MaxiMinArrayObj.MaxMinMethod()
```

Comment: See [Enumerable#max](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) and #min .. even if you can't use these, a max/min is trivial to write in terms of a fold ([#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)) much more elegantly than a Java-style loop xD

Comment: In Ruby we don't use CamelCase for method names, instead we use snake_case. `MaxMinMethod` should be `max_min_method`. Also it's obvious it's a method, so simply call it `max_min`. But, as others mentioned, Ruby already has [`minmax`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax) implemented, so instead of writing your own take advantage of the pre-written one.

Comment: In the `if array[i].to_i > maxNo` and `if array[i].to_i < minNo` you use conversion to integer. In the `maxNo = array[i]` and `minNo = array[i]` you don't use it that (`to_i`). That's kind of error might be hard to find. I would write something like this: `for i in 1...array.length; candidate = array[i].to_i; if candidate > maxNo; # and the rest of the code`. Sawa talked about something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24216271/2597260

Comment: Did any of the answers solved your problem?

Answer (score 6):

It is the combination of two things.

- First, you iterated over `for i in 1..arrayLength`, which iterates past the last element in `array`. After the last element, `array[i]` is `nil`.
- Second, you have the condition `if array[i].to_i < minNo`, which can be satisfied even if `array[i]` is not a number.

Because of that, the `nil` returned by `array[i]` after the last element satisfies the condition due to `nil.to_i` being `0`, and that `nil` is assigned to `minNo`.

Answer (score 6):

I realize you're trying to learn how to code, but, as you do so, it's also important to learn to take advantage of pre-existing solutions. Reinventing wheels will waste your time debugging code.

I'd write the code like:

```
def max_min(ary)
  [ary.max, ary.min]
end

max_min([1,2,4]) # => [4, 1]
```

But, then again, Ruby already has a good `minmax` method:

```
[1,2,4].minmax # => [1, 4]
```

so use it and focus your energy on more interesting things.

If you *have to* see the values in the opposite order, use:

```
[1,2,4].minmax.reverse # => [4, 1]
```

A more verbose/old-school way of doing it is:

```
FIXNUM_MAX = (2 ** (0.size * 8 - 2) - 1)
FIXNUM_MIN = -(2 ** (0.size * 8 - 2))

def max_min(ary)
  return [nil, nil] if ary.empty?
  minval = FIXNUM_MAX
  maxval = FIXNUM_MIN
  ary.each do |i|
    minval = i if i < minval
    maxval = i if i > maxval
  end
  [maxval, minval]
end

max_min([1,2,4]) # => [4, 1]
[1,2,4].minmax.reverse # => [4, 1]
```

That simply loops over the array, checks each value to see if it's either smaller or larger than the last minimum or maximum value, and, if so, remembers it. Once the array is exhausted the values are returned. It's a lot more concise because using `each` removes a lot of the hassle of trying to walk the array using index values. We almost never use `for` in Ruby, especially to walk through an array.

(Technically Ruby can hold values well beyond 4611686018427387903 and -4611686018427387904, which are what `FIXNUM_MAX` and `FIXNUM_MIN` are, but those suffice for most things we want to do.)

Comment: Your verbose method returns a wrong result when `ary` is empty. I don't see why you need to use `FIXNUM_MAX` and `FIXNUM_MIN` at all.

Comment: As I said, that's how we'd do it in the old days; Languages had maximum/minimum values for integers because they were tied to what the CPU supported, and didn't change precision like Ruby can. We had to know the boundaries and would use those to seed the min/max, using the opposite end of the spectrum. As for returning values for an empty array, that's an easy fix.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a good practice to print inside methods as long as you might want to use the results for something else.

Also Ruby comes with all sorts of magic methods to get the maximum and minimum of an array:

```
results = [5, 23, 43, 2, 3, 0].minmax
puts "Maximum no. in the given array: " + results[1]
puts "Minimum no. in the given array: " + results[0]
```

Comment: Ruby has an even more "magic" method: `min, max = [1,2,3].minmax`.

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate from 1 to `arrayLength - 1` (it's an index of the last element). You can use three dots for this:

```
for i in 1...arrayLength
```

Comment: (Why use an index at all?)

Comment: The bug you were hitting involved the i value going 1 past the array bounds. Thus array[i].to_i would = 0 which is less than any value in your array. Then in the next line you assign nil to the minNo variable.

Comment: Your explanation fixed the bug, I just wanted to supply some additional information.

Comment: I wrote the same code in Java as well but it worked without adding -1 to the array length.

Comment: You have `i = 1; i < ArrLength` that equivalent to exactly `1...ArrLength`. `..` includes boundary values.

Answer (score 1):

If I were not allowed to used Ruby's `minmax` method, than I would do it probably like this:

```
array = [4,2,8,3,5]

min, max = nil, nil
array.each do |element|
  min = element if min.nil? || element < min
  max = element if max.nil? || max < element
end

puts [min, max]
# => [2, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this expression for the min and max within ruby, it's a stretch but it works

```
class RubyMinMax

def self.min_function(array=[])
    puts "my array is the following #{array}"
    puts "the length of the array is #{array.length}"
    it = 0
    while array.length > 1
        array.fetch(it).to_i > array.fetch(it-1).to_i ? array.delete_at(it) : array.delete_at(it-1)
        it = array.length-1
    end
    print array[0]
end

def self.max_function(array=[])
    puts "my array is the following #{array}"
    puts "the length of the array is #{array.length}"
    it = 0
    while array.length > 1
        array.fetch(it).to_i < array.fetch(it-1).to_i ? array.delete_at(it) : array.delete_at(it-1)
        it = array.length-1
    end
    print array[0]
end
end

RubyMinMax.min_function([18, 19, 17])

RubyMinMax.max_function([18, 19, 17])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest way you can use `max` and `min` method of array.

```
:001 > [1,4,1,3,4,5].max
 => 5 
:002 > [1,4,1,3,4,5].min
 => 1
```

And if your array may contain `nil` the first `compact` it the use `min` `max`

For example

```
:003 > [1,4,1,3,4,5,nil].compact
=> [1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5]

:004 > [1,4,1,3,4,5].max
 => 5 

:005 > [1,4,1,3,4,5].min
 => 1
```